# CakePHP routes with sub-folders

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem with CakePHP route

```
Router::connect(
    '/catalog/:slug/:slug2/*', array(
        'controller'=>'pages', 
        'action'=>'view'
))
```

When I have url 
`/catalog/something/page:2` - it also catches this link. But it shouldn't, because there is no slash after params `page:2`, How to fix it? Thanks!!

Comment: I hope you've read through [the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)?

Comment: read and still reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this may be helpful.

```
Router::connect(
    '/catalog/:slug/:slug2/*', array(
        'controller'=>'pages', 
        'action'=>'view'
), array('pass' => array('slug', 'slug2')));
```

and in your view file you can write like this to generate a link for above.

```
echo $this->Html->link('link', array(
    'controller' => 'pages',
    'action' => 'view',
    'slug' => 'slug',
    'slug2' => 'slug2'
));
```

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. If I will provide link in your way, I will have slug:x, and slug2:x tags in url - I want to avoid that. So I think there is not rational way to do this, I will need tons of workarounds now, because of this cake bug

Comment: do you want to make the url from `/catalog/something/page:2` to `/catalog/something/2`

Comment: if so then you can pass like this `echo $this->Html->link('link', array(
    'controller' => 'pages',
    'action' => 'view',
    'page' => '2'
));` instead of slug.

Comment: Good idea! It will be easier to make it work in this way! Thanks!

Comment: Oh, there is another place where CakePHP is not flexible - pagination url, I can't define it as unique one without providing controller and action. So I have made it custom, so I can't use your method now, because In that custom method, I'm replaceing 'page:' tag with new number of page :D